# Framework for pairing iOS and Mac apps over WiFi

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, security

I have a Mac app (not suitable for the app store) that I'd like to write a little remote control iOS app for (to be used over local WiFi).
My big issue is the initial pairing of the two apps. I absolutely do not want to allow unsecured traffic between the two, but I'm also hoping not to have to bootstrap a huge pile of code to get them securely talking.
Does anyone know of a framework, or some sample code, which does this sort of thing?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/Discovering,Browsing,AndAdvertisingNetworkServices/Discovering,Browsing,AndAdvertisingNetworkServices.html)

Comment: @rokjarc Thanks, but Bonjour is just for advertising a service, it doesn't do anything to help pair devices securely.

Comment: With help of Bonjour you can find IP and port (usually you just need IP if you use fixed port) of 'master' device/application. After resolving IP:port client can connect to the 'server'. There is no term such as 'pairing' in Wi-Fi. I've used Bonjour (avanhi) in several apps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You want the [MultipeerConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity) framework, a high-level Bonjour implementation.

It allows iOS and macOS devices to securely communicate. You can either use the built in UI with `MCAdvertiserAssistant` and `MCBrowserViewController`, or you can utilize the underlying `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser` and `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` to facilitate the communication.

The trick for secure communication is to set the encryption preference to `required`, which will only allow a connection if both the advertiser and broadcaster opt for encryption.

```
let session = MCSession(peer: self.peerID,
                        securityIdentity: nil,
                        encryptionPreference: .required)
```

Comment: I’ve played with Multipeer before and it seemed unreasonably hard to do decent mutually-authenticated encryption - generating suitable identities on the device required so sketchy third party code 